# Is there no meaning of suggestion in Why don't I (do something)?

Tags: meaning

Why don't we (do something) and Why don't you (do something) have a meaning about the suggestion.

So, I'm confused about Why don't I (do something).
For example, Why don't I believe you? means I can't believe you, I think.

Can you let me understand it clearly?

Comment: *Why don't I explain?* - that's a ***rhetorical*** question, for which I'm assuming the "expected" answer *Since there's obviously **no reason not to explain**, just get on and do it!* Is that enough of an explanation? Why don't you understand it? (That last one is a genuine enquiry, not a rhetorical question! :)

Comment: ...as a rhetorical question, *Why don't I believe you?* implies the expected but unspoken "answer" *Because whatever you're saying is obviously untrue!*

Comment: Then, Is that meaning no reason not to believe in the following conversation? A: I don't do this very often. B: Why don't I believe you?

Comment: I assume there'd be some obvious reason why A's assertion isn't likely to be true - perhaps A is dexterously performing some complicated action, which might suggest that he's done it many times before.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the pronoun used makes any difference. *Why don't (I / you / we / they / he / she)?* All of those pronouns carry (or don't carry) the same level of suggestion. If I ask you *Why don't I believe you?* I could be asking for a legitimate answer just as much as if I ask you *Why don't you believe me?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it is truly rhetorical in that you do await some answer when you ask. It's just that none is forthcoming or satisfactory. It is a way of presenting your current problem to yourself or others for consideration.

When you ask *Why don't I believe you?* you are implying strongly that you do not believe them no matter what they give for an answer. An answer of qualifications and experience would not help. A reassurance of "Trust me" is the common and only appropriate response.

When you ask *Why don't I do something* you are expressing the fact that you are troubled by the current situation. None of the actions you might take look like solutions the problem or you would certainly jump on them.

In both cases an answer is not obvious so the question forms and requires expression if only in frustration.